# Loading Highcharts configuration externally

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have a lot of different charts that i'm rendering using Highcharts. Trying to find a good dynamic way of doing this. This is a proof of concept that I thought would be good. The thing is that the charts have different configurations (and data). So my initial thought is, in combination with mustasche.js, something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="highchart" 
     data-some-other-variable=""
     data-date-from="" 
     data-date-to="" 
     data-template="path/to/graph/graph.mustache"
>
```

Then a simple proof of concept in Javascript

```
var chart = $('.highchart');

$.get(chart.data('template'), function(options) {
    // Do stuff 
    highcharts(options);
});
```

The thing is, the response I get is in pure text. And it can't be parsed into a javascript variable since it's not valid json. (the configuration object has a formater: function() {} inside it). Hence I cannot init highcharts with it. Eval isn't an option for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Give that code a try

```
var chart = $('.highchart');

$.ajax({
   url: chart.data('template'),
   type: "GET"
}, function(data) {
   // Do stuff 
   var options = $.parseJSON(data);
   highcharts(options);
});
```

Comment: The file that I am trying to load, isn't valid JSON. One example of this is:

labels: {
   formatter: function () {
    // stuff for highcharts
   }
  }

Comment: So, you have functions there that can't be executed, right?

Comment: The issue is that I can't convert the external file into a javascript object.

Comment: The problem is that in json you cannot place a functions. So maybe better is prepare something like "main theme" and then call a merge function to combine "theme" with own options for particular chart? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dd05Lr24/1/